# Update all pods error templates not found /Applications

Tags: ios, xcode, git, terminal, cocoapods

I don't understand what problem cocopods has and what I should do to fix it.

I wrote "pod update" from terminal for an old project of mine.

But this error comes out of the terminal:

Updating local specs repositories
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
$ /Applications/CocoaPods 1.5.2.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/bin/git clone
https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master --progress
Cloning into 'master'...
warning: templates not found /Applications
1.5.2.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/share/git-core/templates
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch cocoapods spec master normally by:

1. Finder -> Go to folder -> ~/.cocoapods/repos
2. Run `git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master`

I'm also wondering did you select `Command Line Tools` in XCode settings?

Comment: son, i did as you told me, now I have the "master" directory, but I see that it weighs 1.68 GB! But what is the purpose of this folder that takes up all this space?

Comment: Now I tried to do pod update again but it gives me another error: 

Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
  $ /Applications/CocoaPods 1.5.2.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/bin/git -C
  /Users/name/.cocoapods/repos/master fetch origin --progress
  fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
[!] CocoaPods was not able to update the `master` repo. If this is an unexpected issue and persists you can inspect it running `pod repo update --verbose`

Comment: It's a repo of course, which holds all podspec files of third parties. And it will navigate you from `pod install` to exactly the third parties you want to use.